# R: How to 'aggregate' (or combine) character columns?

Tags: r

I have a df with three columns. Every column has a character or NA and every row has only one character. As this example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("NA","NA","NA","NA","fruits","fruits","fruits","fruits","fruits","fruits"), 
                 b=c("NA","NA","veggies","veggies","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                 c=c("nuts","nuts","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA") )
```

I want to combine all three columns, to get this:

```
1     nuts
2     nuts
3  veggies
4  veggies
5   fruits
6   fruits
7   fruits
8   fruits
9   fruits
10  fruits
```

Using numeric values I would use `aggregate` with `na.rm=TRUE`. However, I don't have any idea how to do this with characters. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: `apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "")`

Comment: If the strings actually read `"NA"` (instead of being `NA`), you can do: `apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(gsub("NA", "", x), collapse = ""))`

Comment: Does are those *supposed* to be missing values, as in `NA_character_`; or `"NA"`, as in string literals, as you have above?

Comment: @MichaelChirico your 2nd answer works fine. Thanks

Comment: @nrussell I imagine this has its roots in how the data was read. N.Varela, you should check if there's an option for specifying `NA_string` or something like that in your data reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col` after converting the string "NA" to real `NA`.  We get the row/column index with `max.col`, extract the values and then convert tot `data.frame`.

```
is.na(df) <- df=='NA'
data.frame(var=df[cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(!is.na(df)))])
#      var
#1     nuts
#2     nuts
#3  veggies
#4  veggies
#5   fruits
#6   fruits
#7   fruits
#8   fruits
#9   fruits
#10  fruits
```

---

Or another option would be

```
data.frame(var= df[cbind(1:nrow(df),(+!is.na(df)) %*% seq_along(df))])
```

Answer (score 0):

To polish the ideas provided in comments, you can do this:

```
data.frame(var = apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(gsub("NA", "", x), collapse = "")) )

      var
1     nuts
2     nuts
3  veggies
4  veggies
5   fruits
6   fruits
7   fruits
8   fruits
9   fruits
10  fruits
```

Comment: that is practically @MichaelChirico answer

Comment: Basically; the only improvement is to match the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The actual data situation may determine whether is is better or worse than the line-by-line method. Here's one way to get a print-out like what you specify:

```
> as.matrix( df[df!="NA"] )
```

Or probably better:

```
> cat( paste( "\n", df[ df!="NA" ] ) )

 fruits 
 fruits 
 fruits 
 fruits 
 fruits 
 fruits 
 veggies 
 veggies 
 nuts 
 nuts
```

Comment: sorry, but I need the same order as in my expected result

Comment: Then just transpose before that operation: `as.matrix( t(df)[ t(df) !="NA"] )`

Comment: @N.Varela   Arrgh. I get a comment, and then when I give a tested response that fully addressed the comment ... I get a downvote (perhaps not from N.Varela, but who knows)? There is no justice.